# How to put separate python variables into different pieces of sql command?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a way to separate python variables that are inserted into an SQL command so you can do something like this?

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connection('Database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

variable1 = str(input("Enter a number: "))
variable2 = str(input("Enter a number: "))

command = ('''SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE firstname = (?) AND lastname = (?)''',
(variable1,), (variable2,)

cursor.execute(command)

conn.close()
```

I realize that this doesn't work I'm just not quite sure what to do to fix it.

Comment: Your question is about how to fetch different `input() commands` or on how to add them to `the sql query string`?

Comment: less to do with input() commands specifically, more to do with just how to insert the variables, so it would be how to add them to the query string

Comment: hey @Tyrell, I eddited my answer because I believe you're missing creating a cursor from your connection.

Comment: i do use a cursor i was just quickly typing it out on here, I'll fix it.

Comment: You were close. `execute()` takes the query arguments in a sequence as its second argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to insert the variables in the SQL statement try using python's fstring for readability (as a test, for production envinronment this could be insecure. [Browser search for `"xkcd"` here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html))

edit, also you might need to create a cursor for the command to work.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connection('Database.db')
# edit, add cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

variable1 = str(input("Enter a number: "))
variable2 = str(input("Enter a number: "))
```

**[Recommended way] Method 1, ? as a placeholder:** make a tuple of value and send as second parameter of cursor.execute()

```
# see the "?" where you want your values
command = f'''SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE firstname = ? AND lastname = ?'''
conditions = (variable1, variable2)    

try:
    cursor.execute(command, conditions)
    # Add something you want to do with the values before closing
    # uncomment bellow if you're INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE something
    #conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    # uncomment bellow if you're INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE something
    #conn.rollback()
    raise Exception(e)
finally: # this will run if it fails or not
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

**[INSECURE if users can inputa data] Method 2, fstrings (for testing):** add the f before the string quotes and the variables inside curly braces {}

```
command = f'''SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE firstname = {variable1} AND lastname = {variable2}'''

# edit, use the cursor to execute and conn to close connection
## Also is a good practice if you're inserting something and an error occur, you do try / excepts with rollback
try:
    cursor.execute(command)
    # Add something you want to do with the values before closing
    # uncomment bellow if you're INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE something
    #conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    # uncomment bellow if you're INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE something
    #conn.rollback()
    raise Exception(e)
finally: # this will run if it fails or not
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: OK this seems to work, it keeps telling me no column to that name but at least it's taking the input now. Also thanks for the tips.

Comment: Great! Are `firstname` and `lastname` available columns to the `USERS` table?

Comment: yes they are, but I'm also using a virtual table with fts5, so I'm not sure if that is what my issue is with the error.

Comment: According to what I read here https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html, FTS5 is supposed to do full-text search (meaning as it searchs in all columns) as an sql query and not usual search by specifying columns conditions.

Comment: Nah you're probably with your head full trying to wrap around many concepts, errors and new stuff at the same time and might be blinding you from small details. Cheers mate

Comment: Thanks for the help, it still answered my question.

Comment: Please do not use string formatting for passing values to queries. It is error prone and may lead to SQL injection. Use the driver's placeholders, `?` in case of sqlite3, and pass the arguments separately to `execute()`.

Comment: High @IljaEverilä, thanks for you input. Could you provide articles/tutorials on how python's (3) sqllite statements as string formatting are prone to errors/injections and why should people use '?' placeholders?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html: "Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure", https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: A concrete example: say that your login checks if the credentials are correct using `f"SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.name = '{name}' AND u.passwd = '{passwd}'"`. I provide you as name `notauser` and as password `' OR name = 'admin' -- `

Comment: And in the above it'd also do to just use `admin' -- ` as name.

Comment: Nice, that's what I've found googling as well. Thanks for including it here and making it easier for whoever lands it here and is a novice. Cheers mate.